# Expression resolves to an unused function

Tags: xcode, swift, function

So I have been messing around with saving and calling from NSUserDefaults and I have made progress but I keep on getting this error.

"Expression resolves to an unused function"

The program is supposed to save a string from a textfield so that if you close the program and open it the string will still be their. Unless, you press save again and then the string (Label) will change.

The problem prevents me from running the program so I have not been able to test the new code that I wrote.

Here is the source code feel free to try it.  All of this is written in swift.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Help
//
//  Created by Lucas on 9/30/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Lucas. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var Savedlbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var Textfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var Label: UILabel!


    var current = ""
    var Saved = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        let currentDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        Savedlbl.text = currentDefault.valueForKey("saved") as? String




        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    @IBAction func Set(sender: AnyObject) {


        setall()


    }
func setall()
    {
        current = Textfield.text!
        Label.text = Textfield.text!
        Savedlbl.text = Textfield.text!


        let currentDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        Savedlbl.text = currentDefault.valueForKey("saved") as? String
         currentDefault.setValue(Saved, forKey: "saved")
            currentDefault.synchronize
            }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: `currentDefault.synchronize` should be `currentDefault.synchronize()` – as suggested by Xcode's autocompletion.

Comment: Thanks that fixed my problem!

Comment: On to more problems!

Comment: Now its not changing to the new text @MartinR

Comment: That is a different problem, so you should ask a new question. But don't forget to reduce your code to a *minimal* self-contained example demonstrating the problem, and add all expected and actual input and output.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that won't happen again.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
currentDefault.synchronize
```

should be:

```
currentDefault.synchronize()
```